# Display Column of a table depending on fDropdown Select

Tags: html, angularjs, datatable

I have a dropdown containing the table headers of the table of I want to display. I want to display a specific column based on the selected value in dropdown. Is This possible? If it is can you give me an insight on how will I do this?  I am using html and angularjs

Comment: source:-https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: @Raziasultana Thanks but what I need is to display table columns that has a header equivalent to the selected values in the dropdown multiselect. I don't hav any idea whre can I start. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle so that i can understand what do you want?

Comment: @Raziasultana can we continue this discussion on chat? thank you very much

Comment: @Raziasultana the concept is like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vXBtP/ but what i want is for the checkboxes to be inside a dropdown multiselect . can you help me with this?